# Summation of complex series

Tags: complex-numbers, summation

Given:
$$S= \sin(x)+\frac15\sin(5x)+\frac19\sin(9x)+\cdots$$

And

$$C= \cos(x)+\frac15\cos(5x)+\frac19\cos(9x)+\cdots$$

Show that $$C+iS=\frac{2e^{ix}}{1-4e^{ix}}$$

Can’t seem to show this given the $1/(4r+1) $term.

Thanks

Comment: Hm, $C$ doesn’t converge when $x=0,$ so I’m not sure your formula is correct.

Comment: Can you show what you’ve tried?  It looks like the derivative of the series $C+iS$ is a geometric series in $e^{4ix}$, so you should be able to sum that.  Then checking the derivative of the given expression matches gets you equality up to an additive constant...

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Using the same idea as @mjqxxxx suggested in the comments:
$$\begin{align}
S&= \sin(x)+\frac15\sin(5x)+\frac19\sin(9x)+\cdots\\
C&= \cos(x)+\frac15\cos(5x)+\frac19\cos(9x)+\cdots\end{align}$$
This means that
$$\begin{align}C+iS&=(\cos x+i\sin x)+\frac{1}{5}(\cos5x+i\sin5x)+\frac{1}{9}(\cos9x+i\sin9x)+\cdots\\&=e^{ix}+\frac{1}{5}e^{5ix}+\frac{1}{9}e^{9ix}+\cdots.\end{align}$$
Hence,
$$\begin{align}\frac{d}{dx}(C+iS))&=ie^{ix}(1+e^{4ix}+e^{8ix}+\cdots)\\
&=ie^{ix}\left(\frac{1}{1-e^{4ix}}\right)\end{align}$$
Can you finish now by integrating with respect to $x$? If you need any more help please don't hesitate to ask :)